# Wordpress Bedrock framework installation white screen of death ("Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes")

Tags: wordpress, installation, env

Problem occurred installing the Wordpress Bedrock framework per its documentation [here](https://roots.io/bedrock/docs/installing-bedrock/).

PHP error: `"Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes"` (or just a "Whitescreen of death" if errors are off/going to logs in php.ini).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bedrock's `.env` file needed quotation marks surrounding the values. So, instead of:

```
AUTH_KEY=generateme
SECURE_AUTH_KEY=generateme
...
```

It needed:

```
AUTH_KEY="generateme"
SECURE_AUTH_KEY="generateme"
...
```

Even though the package https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv can use either. This might be due to the keys that were generated (special characters), or perhaps it just needed the quotes...